# EE conditionals within javascript snippet

Tags: conditionals, snippets, javascript

I am trying to use EE conditional statement within Javascript. The Javascript is called through a EE snippet. Part of the problem is I am using js conditionals right below my EE conditional. Is this even possible with a EE if statement? Do I need to escape my if statement some how? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Here is a simplification of my snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
...

{if add_option_on=="On"}
if (thisForm.os2.value == "") {
 alert('Please choose a {exp:channel:entries channel="products" disable="member_data|pagination" limit="1"}{customize_option_label}{/exp:channel:entries}');
 return false;
}
{/if}

...

</script>
```

Comment: What is `add_option_on`? Is that a global variable?

Comment: No it's a channel field {add_option_on}

Comment: Of the `products` channel?

Comment: yes {add_option_on} is a checkbox type channel field of the products channel. Thanks @Siebird for helping me clarify my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try turning off javascript protection to allow the conditionals to parse: `$config['protect_javascript'] = 'n';`

Also, I would wrap the channel entries tag around the conditional like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
...
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" disable="member_data|pagination" limit="1"}
{if add_option_on=="On"}
if (thisForm.os2.value == "") {
 alert('Please choose a {customize_option_label}');
 return false;
}
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
...

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Siebird that did the trick! Looks like I overlooked having my EE conditional nested within a channel entries tag. Thanks again.

Comment: Yep no problem!

Comment: So what is `$config['protect_javascript'] = 'n';` doing?

Comment: You may even be able to get rid of that as it's not a advanced conditional. The `protect_javascript` config variable prevents the advanced conditionals (ie. if:else) parser from processing anything inbetween the tags. I believe the issue was where you had your channel tags ;)

Comment: I tried `protect_javascript` to `'y'` and it did not work. I looked this hidden configuration variable up on the EE docs for more explanation. If anyone else is wondering how this is used, you can read more about it here [-->](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/hidden_configuration_variables.html#protect-javascript).